# How can I store value of an variable using Bundle object in a fragment on rotation?

Tags: android

I am trying to save the value of count variable in onSaveInstanceState() method on rotation of my device but every time I rotate the device the counter variable starts from 0. Can some one help me to find the solution.Using the same approach I had already saved a string value.

```
package com.example.rajat.fragments;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class FragmentClass extends Fragment {
    Button button;
    int count;
    String key1 = "counter";
    Communicator comm;
    int key;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("onCreate", "onCreate() called");

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        comm = (Communicator) getActivity();

        button = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            count = savedInstanceState.getInt(key1, 1);
            Log.e("onCreate", "onActivityCreated() called value of count :" + count);


        }

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                count++;
                key = count;
                Log.e("onCreate", "count value : " + count);
                comm.respond("The button is clicked " + count + " times");

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putInt(key1, count);
        Log.d("onCreate", "onSavedInstanceState() called value of count :" + count);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add this to your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

and then add this line to your manifest, inside your activity tag:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```